# Unable to execute multi-command in power shell

Tags: windows, powershell, command

I'm working on power shell script using windows 2012 server, that do simple two functions

- open powershell as an administrator
- change the directory to c:\user\scrpt.bat

the code is:

```
powershell -Command "& {powershell Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs; Set-Location C:\}
```

the problem is not when execute the first part, it's in the other part which is:

```
Set-Location C:\}
```

My question is there any way after running powershell as administrator execute the next command ?

I already tried to use semicolon ";" but no luck

Comment: if you're running a .bat file, why not just put all of that in the .bat file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change directory for the process you're spawning - use -WorkingDirectory option:

```
powershell -Command "& { Start-Process PowerShell -Verb RunAs -WorkingDirectory 'D:' }"
```